Behaviour problem in dog
I have one male age 5 and female age 5 and half and whenever my female comes to heat my male is piss everywhere he urine all the clothes all the chair we put dog barriers but he jump from the fence and urine everywhere my couch clothes and I am putting apart my female every time but my dog don’t eat and messed up my house and I am almost 9 month pregnant what I can do I am very upset from my dog behaviour my female come at heat every 3rd month and she’s on heat almost 21 days.

"what can I do" spay and neuter your dogs, for starters.

I do understand that this is extremely problematic for you, but unfortunately this is 100% normal and natural behavior for a male dog.
When your female is in heat, she produces special pheromones that spread through the air like perfume. You cannot block these pheromones and when your male smells them, it causes him to become sex-crazy. The urinating is his attempt to convince the female to have sex with him.
The best solution short-term is probably a chemical castration. Please talk to your vet, because there are permanent and non-permanent solutions, but they can have severe side effects, so your dog should be monitored by your vet. They also need some time to actually take effect.
If your male has a tendency to be aggressive towards strangers, I strongly suggest a temporary chemical castration, because studies show that 30% of castrated dogs become even more aggressive.
You could also fix either the female or the male with a traditional operation. From experience: castrating males is much easier than spaying females, so this operation tends to be cheaper and have less complications. Spaying a female that is currently in heat is extremely dangerous and should only ever be done in emergency situations.
